After adding the electrophile (BOMe3) in an halogen exchange (nBuLi) reaction, why do we leave the reaction stir overnight?
Very basic question.
In all the procedures for halogen exchange reactions reported using boronic compounds, the reaction is left to run ON at room temperature after addition of the boronic specie.
In theory, the Lithium intermediate is extremely reactive and should react instantaneously. Has anyone ever seen a study which looks at the evolution of these reactions to see whether they need 12 hours to arrive to completion?
Example of a procedure:
Procedure for borylation using halogen exchange]1
Issued from (supp info):
Butterfly Effects Arising from Starting Materials in Fused-Ring Electron Acceptors
Tengfei Li, Yao Wu, Jiadong Zhou, Mengyang Li, Jingnan Wu, Qin Hu, Boyu Jia, Xiran Pan, Maojie Zhang, Zheng Tang, Zengqi Xie, Thomas P. Russell, and Xiaowei Zhan*
J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2020, 142, 47, 20124–20133
https://doi.org/10.1021/jacs.0c09800

I don't think you need to. This may just be what they did the first time, found it worked and stuck to it.

"Overnight" can imply "the reaction was set up arvo, too late for the intentional quench and proper workup the same day". Some labs (more likely in industry, than in academia) are strict to shut the entries by time X. You usually still can leave the lab (perhaps not the building), but your work in & moves between the labs can trigger an alarm (motion detector, CCTV) as prelude to get to know the folks of (campus) security. Without a solid clearance in advance, this creates hassle for you and your boss. As an undergrad intern I once had to pay partly for their drive to the remote/suburban lab.

Makes sense. Thank you!
